# nested regex replacements (tag wrapping)

Tags: php, regex, nested, replace

I need to make multiple (nested) text replacements (e.g. wrap all found strings with tag SPAN for highlighting purposes) with a bunch of regular expressions, but... see code:

```
<?php

// Sample workaround code:
$html = "hello world";

$regex_array = array(
    '/world/i',
    '/hello world/i'
);

foreach ( $regex_array as $regex ) {
    if ( preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches) ) {
        foreach ( $matches[0] as $match ) {
            $html = str_replace($match, '<span>' . $match . '</span>', $html);
        }
    }
}

print '<h4>Result:</h4>' 
. htmlentities($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
print '<h4>Expected result:</h4>'
. htmlentities('<span>hello <span>world</span></span>', ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

The result is:

```
hello <span>world</span>
```

but the expected result is:

```
<span>hello <span>world</span></span>
```

How can I do that?

**Yes, I could change the order of regex rules and it could solve the problem, but I really CAN NOT DO THAT!**

Comment: why can't you change the order of regexes ?

Comment: Your example is needlessly abstract I believe.

Comment: @mario: yes it is, but I still believe it's possible.

Comment: Well, then accept my shot in the dark options: recursive regex, or a match lookup table / switch in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead of `preg_match_all` + `str_replace`:

```
function handle_matches($matches) {
    return '<span>' . $matches[0] . '</span>';
}
foreach ( $regex_array as $regex ) {
    $html = preg_replace_callback($regex, 'handle_matches', $html);
}
```

Or with PHP5.3:

```
foreach ( $regex_array as $regex ) {
    $html = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {
        return '<span>' . $matches[0] . '</span>';
    }, $html);
}
```

For the tag order problem, there is no real solution is you can't change there order or modify them.

Comment: `$match` is undefined in `handle_matches`. `$matches` is some sort of array/hash so it doesn't look like a typo.